# What is the proper CSS media query to get Android phones to use the mobile format in landscape mode?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, responsive-design

I am building a responsive theme via CSS media queries for a client site. It's showing the mobile site on iPhone and Android in portrait mode, but on Android the regular site is showing in landscape mode (the iPhone shows the mobile site in landscape).

Here is the media query I'm using on my thin CSS file:

```
all and (max-width: 480px), (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Is there perhaps a different width for most Android phones I can accomodate?

Answer (score 1):

There's no size in pixels that could be considered a future-proof standard.

Try using a physical width (such as 15cm) rather than a size in pixels that will vary widely from device to device.

Answer (score 1):

Most new Android phones are probably over 800px in width for landscape mode (which falls under more of a tablet portrait). What you may want to add though is max-height as well, that could detect that under 500px or so is a "mobile landscape" and adjust a few things that you may need to differ from the full mode.